# Is there any way to add alternate pages with static content in pdf (PHP pdf generation)

Tags: php, codeigniter, tcpdf, fpdf, mpdf

I am generating a pdf using php. PDF data will be coming from  the database. I wanted to insert terms and conditions in even page. 
Pages 1,3,5..will be having data from the database and pages 2,4,6.. will be having static terms and condition text.

Is there any ways to do it using any php-pdf library?

Comment: the way you are adding dynamic text, in the same way you can add static text as well.

Comment: I believe it can be done with almost any php-pdf library and only requires you to insert the desired content on the specified pages. I suggest you settle on a php-pdf library and from their documentation investigate how you would do it with their library. I used to use fpdf for pdf generation, but have moved to phpDocX as it offers so many nice features and saves me a lot of time. It is not free though.

Comment: @ Niranjan N Raju, I wanted to add page in between unconditionally. If my PDF is 3 pages, how I can add 2nd page as my static text apge. PDF geeration is dynamic

Comment: but u know where to add... so u can add static ext there.